# Unable to get _id which is not ObjectID with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I can't access to `_id` of any `mongoose.model` object. I know there are a lot of similar answers but none of it solved my problem. I am using `mongoose` and `TypeScript`.

I've existing collection which contains data with existing `Mixed` `_id`:

```js
{
   _id: 10,
   name: "someString",
   email: "someString",
}
...
```

I've Schema and interface:

```js
const UserModel: Schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
});

export interface IUser extends Document {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserModel);
```

and I try to select some user:

```js
UserModel.findOne({email:data.email}).then((user)=>{
    console.log(user);
    // I get everything without _id
    // { name: "someString", email: "someString" } 
    console.log(user.id);
    // null
});
```

---

#### Another attempt

I've also tried to set `_id` to `false` in options:

```js
const UserModel: Schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
}, { _id: false });
```

and I tried to select some user:

```js
UserModel.findOne({email:data.email}).then((user)=>{
    console.log(user);
    // I get everything with _id
    // { _id: 10, name: "someString", email: "someString" } 
    console.log(user.id, user._id);
    // but it is not accessible
    // null, undefined
});
```

---

#### Note

If I create document record through mongoose it creates `_id` as `ObjectId()` and it is selectable.

Comment: Does it work if you add `{ _id: number }` to `IUser`?

Comment: As a typescript issue, adding `{ _id: number }` to `IUser` makes `_id` accessible without errors: [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/RwReLW).  But I don't know if it is actually present at runtime or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose expects an ObjectID for `_id`

Add your custom type to the schema

```
const UserModel: Schema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
});
```

The `_id` index can't be modified so don't worry about adding index options.

It's usually best to leave Mongo to use it's ObjectID.

Comment: That's it. Thank you for explanation.